# How to call a Android ndk build .so file in another Android application?

Tags: android, android-ndk

I have an requirement which i have to build `.so` file using `NDK` build in Android and I have to call some of the methods from the `.so` file in my other Android application.

What I have tried so far.

I have taken the .so file from the lib folder of my Android project and put in my other application libs folder where I should call that .so file. I have used the below code:

**Note:** I am using ECLIPSE

```
static {
        System.loadLibrary("NativeCode");
    }
```

and also tried with full path of library

```
static {
        System.loadLibrary("fullpath\NativeCode");
    }
```

both the cases its giving unsatisfiedLinkError that mean it's not getting the path of my `.so` file.

Answer (score 0):

You need to have your `libNativeCode.so` in the `jni` folder of your root, and not in the `libs` or `lib` folder

Here is a nice tutorial : http://www3.ntu.edu.sg/home/ehchua/programming/android/android_ndk.html

Alternatively, you can use following commands:

```
    adb shell
    $echo $PATH
```

What it will do is display a path like this :

> /sbin:/vendor/bin:/system/sbin:/system/bin:/system/xbin

You can have your `.so` in any of these folders like `/system`, `/system/bin`, `/system/sbin`. (Remember, but you would need to manually copy it, and it is not a good idea to do so for an app)

Edit :
You can not call any JNI function in your app, because the signature. You need to have a JNI wrapper (a `.so` JNI lib that in turn uses the `.h` header file to call the JNI function of the other library). This is because JNI is very sensitive to signatures. So, as I recommended earlier, follow the tutorial !

Comment: But this examples only saying to build an android ndk application but my question is i have already a .so file how to use it in another android application it might or might not be a android ndk project

Comment: as you said i put the .so file in jni folder but tis not working

Comment: @AbhijitChakra Edited my answer. Take a look

Answer (score 0):

In order to get your .so library to be loaded using loadLibrary() you'll have to copy the **libNativeCode.so** lib into the jniLibs/architecture folder.

The folder should be located under ***src/main/jniLibs/armeabi-v7a*** of your Android Application module (assuming you're using Android Studio).

After you copy the libraries, add the following line to your build.gradle located at the app module folder:

```
assert file("./src/main/jniLibs/armeabi-v7a/libNativeCode.so").exists()
```

After you'll complete the above steps it should load the lib properly.

If the libNativeCode.so is located at the wrong path, the Gradle build will fail.

Good luck,

Comment: Hi, it is only for gradle builds.